# Como hacer que chrome omita la traducción del texto de un div?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, extensión-google-chrome

El problema es que estoy creando una extensión de chrome que me agrega un div editable en las páginas web, pero cuando el traductor de chrome traduce las paginas tambien se traduce el contenido del div. tengo que evitar este comportamiento así que necesito una forma de omitir la traducción solo en ese div. e tratado colocando el atributo `lang="es"`al div. pero no funciona.

HTML

```
<div lang="es" class="paper" id="paperEx1" contenteditable="true" style="color: black;">Aqui el usuario puede escribir</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar la clase CSS llamada `notranslate` del traductor de texto de Google Chrome, es una clase para evitar que traduzca ese texto en concreto.

Ejemplo aplicandolo tu `div`:

```
<div lang="es" class="paper notranslate" id="paperEx1" contenteditable="true" style="color: black;">Aqui el usuario puede escribir</div>
```

(Ahora si usas el traductor de Google Chrome en la página no traducirá el texto con la clase aplicada)

Ejemplo aplicándolo a un elemento `p`:

```
<p class="notranslate">Hello</p>
```

Comment: funciona bien. Gracias